# How to store a specific element from a csv into a variable?

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, variables

I have a csv file called Energy.csv and it's very simple:

> Building A,150
>
> Building B,160

I would like to import the csv into Ruby and print the second row, second column element (160). This is what I have so far but I don't know how to improve this code.

```
require 'csv'

class CSVImport
  
   energyusageA = Array.new
   energyusageB = Array.new
   CSV.foreach('CSV/Energy.csv') do |row|
       energyusageA = row[1]
       energyusageB = row[2]   
   end 
   puts energyusageB[1]

end
```

Comment: Tip: In Ruby use `[ ]` in preference to the more formal and needlesly verbose `Array.new`.

Comment: Also, Ruby treats capital letters as special syntax so avoid using them in method or variable names. The convention is `energyusage_a` and such, though that itself is problematic as `var1` and patterns like that are best avoided by using proper data structures like an Array or Hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read this in quickly if it's a small file and memory isn't a constraint:

```
CSV.open('CSV/energy.csv').read[1][1]
```

Where that pulls the second row's second value as everything's zero-indexed in Ruby.

In your code you have it wrapped inside of a `class` definition but that doesn't really make sense unless you're defining methods. Yes you can run executable code there in that context but that's reserved for other situations like meta-progamming.

A Ruby-style design looks like this:

```
class CSVReader
  def initialize(path)
    @path = path
  end

  def value(row: 1, col: 1)
     CSV.open(@path).read[row][col]
  end
end
```

Where you can call it like:

```
CSVReader.new('CSV/energy.csv').value
CSVReader.new('CSV/energy.csv').value(row: 4, col: 2)
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were quite close.

To get second row you can do it the following way:

```
require 'CSV'

second_row = Array.new
CSV.foreach('energy.csv') do | row |
    second_row << row[1]
end
```

To get the second element you just need to access second column element (since ruby is 0-based it is `1`):

`second_row[1]` will print you `=>"160"`.

**Edit** I think I need to explain one more thing.  The difference between `=` (assignment) and `<<` (appending).

The `=` assigns the variable the right side.
The `<<` appends the right side to the end of an Array.

You can try it out on the following test:

```
test = Array.new
test = 'Yo' => this assigns string to the test (*"Yo\n"* will be stored in the *test8 variable)
OR
test << 'Yo' => this appends to the empty array the string 'Yo' so the *Array* will look like this *["Yo"]*.
```